# FedEx API ('BAD.REQUEST.ERROR': Missing or duplicate parameters... )

Tags: javascript, python, php, python-requests

Post request to fedex Authorization Api is returning an error. I've tried doing this request in PHP, Javascript and python in a number of methods, yet only the python script is working properly, despite the changes being minimal. Bellow is the code used for python and javascript in order.
I've tried sending the payload as a json object, as an array and string, yet none has worked.
Please help me figure out what may be the error.
Thank you in advance

//python (working and returning the token)

```
import requests

url = "https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/oauth/token"

Client_id = "****************************"
Client_secret = "****************************"

payload = {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": Client_id,
    "client_secret": Client_secret
}
    
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }

response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)

json_response = response.json()
token = json_response["access_token"]

print(token)
```

//javascript (code: 'BAD.REQUEST.ERROR', message: 'Missing or duplicate parameters. Please modify your request and try again.')

```
Client_id = "****************************"
Client_secret = "****************************"

Payload =  {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'cliend_id': Client_id,
    'client_secret': Client_secret
}

fetch('https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/oauth/token',{
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(Payload),
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
    
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data =>console.log(data))
.then(err =>console.log(err))
```

Comment: Typo in payload props?  (Client <-> cliend)

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that your payload is having the **correct** data / format:

```
grant_type

Specify Type of customer requesting the Oauth token.
Valid Values: client_credentials, csp_credentials, client_pc_credentials
Note:
client_credentials - should be used for customers.
csp_credentials - should be used for Compatible Provider customers.
client_pc_credentials – should be used for Proprietary Parent Child customers.

client_id

Specify the Client ID also known as API Key received during FedEx Developer portal registration.
Example: XXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXX

client_secret

Specify the Client secret also known as Secret Key received during FedEx Developer portal registration.
Example: XXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXX
```

Then you may use the following sample code to do the job (JS):

```
var data = JSON.stringify(Payload);
  
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.withCredentials = true;
  
  xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    }
  });
  
  xhr.open("POST", "https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/oauth/token");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.send(data);
```